# Stripping HTML tags from TextArea Element to perform assertion in testcafe

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a few text area fields that are formatted like this. This is seeded into the DB like so.

```
<table style="line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td style="padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
            <p>Hello <strong>[[Contact First Name]]</strong>!</p>
            <p>Your unsubscription request to the following [[Tenant Name]] program has been declined:</p>
            <ul><li>[[Program Name]]</li></ul>
            <p>Thank you,</p>
            <p>[[Tenant Name]]</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Has anyone got any insights into how I can assert this textarea without all the tags and just the text?

I have tried textcontent, innertext, value in conjunction w/eql, contains just hit a brick wall.

```
await t.expect(messagingDetailsPage.emailBodyHTML.textContent).contains(userdata.emailbodyhtml,"Email Body in HTML Match Not Found")
```

Comment: Amessihel - this is actually a table within a TextArea. I have other tables w/textcontent I am asserting and I know that works. This is only my Selector is actually a TextArea with a table embedded within.

Comment: I am not intending to do any conversion. Just want to run an assertion on the content of the textarea and because of it being within a table - it seems to be causing some annoyance.

Comment: Simpler Question - how can I detect a table embedded within a TextArea - so maybe I can add conditional logic to assert either ways.

Comment: a bit of a background we have a lot of message templates we ship out of the box and when viewed in the UI they are loaded into a TextArea and some are formatted with just plain page breaks and line breaks but some have rich content like the table I talked off. so the assertion part of that text area against an expected value which I have it in JSON format is what I am battling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a typical task, since the `textarea` element does not support the `innerText` property as expected.
You can use a workaround though. Create a div element and set its `innerHTML` property from 'textarea.value'.
See the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<textarea>
<table style="line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 
100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;line-height: 1.6em;margin:0;margin-bottom:15px;border:none;background:none;font-size: 1em;width: 100%;width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="width: 100%;">
        <td style="padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;padding:5px;border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: top;"
            valign="top">
            <p>Hello <strong>[[Contact First Name]]</strong>!</p>
            <p>Your unsubscription request to the following [[Tenant Name]] program has been declined:</p>
            <ul><li>[[Program Name]]</li></ul>
            <p>Thank you,</p>
            <p>[[Tenant Name]]</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

test

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `...`;

const getTextAreaText = ClientFunction(() => {
    var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    var div      = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = textarea.value;

    return div.innerText;
});

test('test', async t => {
    const text = await getTextAreaText();

    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: will try that Alex.

Comment: Alex, since I have multiple textareas on that page, I gave the actual selector id itself and when this is placed within the test file, works beautifully. However when am attempting to extract this and put it in a page model. I cannot seem to be able to quite understand the usage.

Comment: I did get it to work finally. But the assertion is still a pain as there is definite formatting issues between what is in the innertext and how its is on my json data file. I may have to employ a regular exp stripping for unnecessary spaces/line breaks etc.